# How to use Aurelia.io with Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, aurelia

I got the Aurelia starter project working in VS Community edition and I can view the web page in the browser no problem.

http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/getting-started

I opened the same project in VS Code but I cant figure out how to run the program. From what I have been reading ctrl F5 is suppose to run the program but its asking me for json configuration and task runner configurations. I have no idea about what its asking. In VS I can just hit RUN and not have to do any of this setup. Can anyone suggest a tutorial on how to set up the run configuration? VS Code seems complicated, should I stick with VS and forget VS Code?

Comment: More information on how VSCode tasks work in the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks, looks like it can auto detect the gulp tasks but no idea if it will work with a VS project, I suspect not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any of the skeleton templates are setup to "run" from within VS Code. Instead use VS Code for editing your source only, and use the console to build and serve the app as a web site.

Try using the Skeleton-ES2016 template found here: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016

The README says it all, but basically you will end up running `gulp watch` from the command line, which will build your app in a way that is suitable for browsing as a web site at `http://localhost:9000`.